How are combustion chamber baffles cooled?
Are they cooled the same way as the chamber walls, or do they somehow not require cooling?

Are you asking about the baffles sometimes found on the injector face, the acoustic cavity baffles, or something else?

@OrganicMarble the baddies that stop combustion instability

The injector face baffles and the acoustic cavity baffles are both provided for that reason.

@OrganicMarble probably the injector face baffles. I have no idea what this acoustic cavity even is.

It's easier to find details on old engines, so here's how the iconic F-1 cooled its injector baffles.
tl;dr they were cooled by the fuel

The thrust chamber injector distributes the propellants into the combustion chamber at the proper mixture ratio, pressure, and spray pattern to initiate and sustain stable combustion. It is a CRES, 31-ring, plate-type injector, divided into 13 compartments by 2 circular and 12 radial baffles, which dampen tangential and transverse combustion instability shock waves generated during combustion. The compartments are identified numerically, 1 through 13, and the baffles alphabetically, A through N. (See figure 1-9.) The 31-ring grooves consist of 16 fuel ring grooves alternating with 15 oxidizer ring grooves. The fuel ring grooves are supplied with fuel from the injector manifold by 32 radial passages, and the oxidizer ring grooves are supplied with oxidizer from the oxidizer dome by axially drilled holes.  Fourteen copper rings, orifice-drilled to provide a doublet fuel-on-fuel impingement, and 2 circular, fuel-cooled copper baffles are brazed to the fuel ring grooves. Fifteen copper rings, orificed-drilled to provide a doublet oxidizer-on-oxidizer impingement, are brazed to the oxidizer ring grooves. The twelve radial fuel-cooled, copper baffles are supplied with fuel by the outer circular baffle to which they are brazed. Two igniter fuel housings in each of the 12 outer compartments and one igniter fuel housing in the center compartment, connected by individual fuel feed tubes to the igniter manifold, inject igniter fuel to the compartments. The center of compartment No. 13 is threaded for the attachment of the throat plug shaft.


(All highlights mine. Yellow highlight shows the "outer circular baffle".)
Reference: R-3896-1 TECHNICAL MANUAL ENGINE DATA F·l ROCKET ENGINE (generously made available in this answer)
This schematic shows how the fuel flowed through the baffle and was then dumped out through small holes at the tip of the baffle.

Here is a photo of a straight baffle segment showing the dump cooling holes.

Additional material from Heroic Relic's comprehensive F-1 baffle page.

Yes, but how are they "supplied" with fuel? Are they hollow, or do they have a cooling jacket?

@AbdullahisnotanAmalekite they are hollow

@Ludo indeed! Added some detail.
